# if negative determinant -> not positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

If $\det(A)$ is $< 0$, then $A$ is not a positive semidefinite matrix.

How can I prove that statement?

Comment: hint: First consider the case where $A$ is diagonal, then generalize to arbitrary matrices (in particular $A$ has a negative eigenvalue since $\det A<0$)

Comment: A matrix may have complex eigenvalues.

Comment: But hermitian matrices don't.  On the other hand, some authors allow "positive semidefinite" to include non-hermitian matrices whose hermitian parts are positive semidefinite.  In that case, can the determinant be negative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\det A$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $A$, $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda<0$. Let $v$ be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. But then $v^t.A.v=\lambda\lVert v\rVert^2<0$.

Comment: If $\lambda < 0$, $ -\lambda \Vert v \Vert^2 > 0$ 

Comment: @RobertLewis I've edited my answer. Thank you.